# Recording marker data on change (Google maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have just started using the Google Maps API, it's for a service I have on my site; basically when a user is adding  a post they have an option of setting a location using the google maps API, I have created the Google maps API key and connected it, I have also added the draggable marker and a location search box. So it is fully function at the moment.

The only thing that I can't get my head around is how to record the longitude and latitude into two hidden inputs with javascript:

```
<input type="hidden" id="mk-longitude" value="//marker longitude value" />
<input type="hidden" id="mk-latitude" value="//marker latitude value" />
```

So, it should, using Javascript record the markers longitude and latitude on change inside these two inputs and then on submit they would get submitted to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works to get updated lat/long from user.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(event){
       document.getElementById("mk-latitude").value = event.latLng.lat();
       document.getElementById("mk-longitude").value = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

*Side: marker is your custom draggable marker.*

Comment: the marker is not a custom made by me, it is the google maps marker that you could add in the properties and then just switch
 `draggable: true`

Comment: Hey, I have got it working now, I had a wrong variable definer the whole time.. It's working perfectly now though *facepalm*

Comment: @BeginnerP: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey @Div, sorry about that, I just did so! :)